# Get DBContext from ObjectContext

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext, objectcontext

I'm using the latest versions of ASP.NET MVC, SQL Server, and Entity Framework. I am *not* using code first.

I can easily create an object context using the class generated by my EDMX file.

But is there any way to obtain a `DBContext` object from that class? I would like to use its extended features.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can add a code generation item for a `DbContext`. Right-click on the design surface of the edmx and choose "Add code generation item" and select DbContext Generator from the Add New Item dialog (you may have to look in online templates). This will create a t4 template that generates a `DbContext`.

If you want to keep working with the `ObjectContext` API, but sometimes want to switch to `DbContext` you can create a `DbContext` with [the constructor accepting an `ObjectContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696505%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)  as parameter.

Comment: Either option would be just what I was looking for. Thanks.